# ¿Cómo resolver un sistema de ecuaciones lineales con parámetros?

Tags: r, matrices

Preciso resolver sistemas de ecuaciones lineales en R pero con parámetros, es decir en abstracto:

Por ejemplo uno de 3x3 tal que:

```
(M*M)x + M y + z = 0
L*L x + Ly  + z  = 10
((L-M)(L-M)/4 )x + (L-M)/2 y +z = 10/4
```

intente definir asi

```
B= array(c(m*m,m,1,l*l,l,1,(l-m)*(l-m)/4,(l-m)/2,1),dim=c(3,3))
```

para resolverlo con `solve` pero evidentemente no me deja, me pone error en el arreglo, el objeto `m` no es encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que quieres definir una matriz de 3x3 como B. El problema es que m y l deben ser definidos antes que B. No existen m y l como objetos en R, entonces simplemente da error.
Por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, tienes un sistema de 3 ecuaciones con 3 incógnitas x, y, z pero además tienes dos parámetros M y L. Puedes hacer una función de 2 parámetros que te de la solución par M y L dados:

```
resolver <- function(m, l) {
  B <- matrix(c(m*m,m,1,l*l,l,1,(l-m)*(l-m)/4,(l-m)/2,1),ncol=3,nrow=3)
  solve(B, c(0,10,10/4))
}
# ejemplos
> resolver(1,2)
[1]  45.000000  -9.166667 -33.333333
```

Fíjate que hay pares de M, L que hacen que B sea singular, es decir que det(B) = 0.
Por ejemplo de la primera y segunda ecuación, M y L no pueden ser iguales, porque quedan dos ecuaciones iguales pero una es cero y la otra 10. Tampoco pude ser M = -L porque la tercera queda L^2 x + Ly + z = 10/4 y la segunda queda L^2 x + Ly + z = 10.  Por ejemplo

```
> resolver(5,5)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in solve.default(B, c(0, 10, 10/4)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0 
> resolver(-2,2)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in solve.default(B, c(0, 10, 10/4)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0
```

Comment: como puedo obtener los resultados de x, y & z en funcion de M y L poniendo como restricciones o asumiendo que no se cumplen esas condiciones para singularidad?
Quiero que me quede por ejemplo x= 3M  ( no quiero en principio sustituir M por ningun valor!)

Comment: @LucianoSpinelli, este comentario agregalo a tu pregunta, fijate que ayer justo te respondí exactamente lo mismo que Marcelo, es decir la pregunta tal como está nos induce a responderte de esta forma. Saludos.

Comment: Para obtener fórmulas explícitas de x, y, z en función de parámetros no valuados, se debería aplicar la regla de Cramer, no se si hay algún software que lo haga de manera simbólica. Hay varios que hacen los cálculos numéricos